# Django model form field: use disabled but still pase (calculated) values to form.is_valid()

Tags: django

Assume I have a model class `A` with a mandatory text field `b` (and other fields).

I want to create a **model form** where under certain circumstances (determined in the form's `__init__`) the value for `b` is calculated and not shown in the form. It seems that setting `disabled` is the way to go, which, according to [this docs entry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled), will ignore any value passed but instead use "the form’s initial data". However, the following does not do what I hoped it would do:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.TextField()
    c = ... 

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('b', 'c', 'd')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if complicated_test(*args, **kwargs):
            field = self.fields['b']
            field.disabled = True
            field.initial = 'Bla'
```

This *does* disable the field, but seems to ignore the manually given value `Bla`,
which in my case will make `form.is_valid()` fail (as my model really expects `Bla` to be in there).

Questions:

1. Is `field.initial = 'Bla'` really supposed to fail in this situation, or it this a weird bug in my setup?
2. If no bug: Can I set "the form’s initial data" in some other way?
3. What alternatives are recommended? In my case, I do not see a natural place to change the data in the view, for instance as `form.is_valid()` already fails. (Otherwise I guess I could just create the `A`-instance from the form and then set `A.b='Bla'` in the view, before saving?)

Remark: A popular answer to similar questions I found here seems to be "use `hidden` instead of `disabled`", but that seems weird? Why would I pass hidden data back and forth some forms hoping that the user will not screw up the data, if I have the data at the server anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, it seems that

- As claimed in the doc mentioned in the question, `cleaned_data` [does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a9c6ab03560424ed7dff24849c8ddaa3e1eae62e/django/forms/forms.py#L385) get its value from the form's `initial` value for a `disabled` form field.
- However, a **model form** does not use this `cleaned_data` value for a `disabled` field, [but rather](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a9c6ab03560424ed7dff24849c8ddaa3e1eae62e/django/forms/models.py#L51) the model's `default` value (if it exists).

So it seems that one really has to use a hidden field instead, which seems a bit silly...